# How to fix compilation errors in MSVC related to declaration of anonymous struct inside a 'for' loop?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, compiler-errors, c++14, anonymous-struct

We can declare anonymous `struct` inside `for` loop as [below (g++)](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ba666d2ea62b4b1d):

```
for(struct { bool OK = true; } s; s.OK; s.OK = false)
  std::cout << "Hello, world!\n";
```

But, this code results in compilation error in [MSVC](https://rextester.com/l/cpp_online_compiler_visual) as:

> **source_file.cpp(7): error C2332: 'struct': missing tag name**
>   source_file.cpp(7): error C2062: type 'bool' unexpected
>   source_file.cpp(7): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed.
>   Note: C++ does not support default-int

How to fix it?

---

**Version**:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community>cl
>   Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version **19.14.26430** for x86
>   Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Comment: Which version of MSVC? What flags and options do you set or use when building?

Comment: That online VC compiler seems to be a developmental version (19.00.23506) judging by the "00" as the second field. Your code compiles without warning or error in Version 19.24.28316 for x64 - however 'strict' I make the settings.

Comment: @AdrianMole, I have updated the compiler version in the question. Is there a way to fix it with the older version? Or is 19.24 is too improved compared to 19.14?

Comment: You could work around by changing `for (A;B;C){D}` to `{ A; for(;B;C){D} }`

Comment: @M.M, I already did that. This `for` loop is a part of macro and hence it will change meanings at certain place e.g. `if(xyz) for(...) {} statement;` will have different meanings. Regardless of that, the original problem still persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please not that MSVC 19.14 shows the `error C2062: type 'bool' unexpected` even for a named struct `S` as in this example:

```
  for(struct S { bool OK = true; } s; s.OK; s.OK = false)
    std::cout << "Hello, world!\n";
```

Demo: https://godbolt.org/z/Ev1GMGMYd

I think the easiest fix would be to upgrade to the next compiler version MSVC 19.15 where both issues are fixed. Demo: https://godbolt.org/z/W14dvW5eW